# How do I override this pattern? django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to override the template located in the `forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input_option.html` directory, but it's not working for me. Is it possible to do this at all?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the same template path `django/forms/widgets/input_option.html` in any of your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Django will iterate over all `INSTALLED_APPS` and look for a template with the given path, `django/forms/widgets/input_option.html` in your case. The last found file will be used as the template for rendering.

You can find an example and explanation in the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render